# Let textarea define the height of table row

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have a textarea and a multiline text in a table in two different columns.
The textarea is resizeable and thus I want the textarea to determine the height of the tablerow and the multiline text to be just as tall as the textarea (overflowing everything that can not be displayed).

The problem is that I obviously can not set a fixed height for the scrollable text, but if I do not, it takes up all the space and does not overflow.

It wont let me set the height of the `tr` and I tried all kinds of display and height options.

Is there any way to accomplish that?

---

Here is working example of what I am working with:

```css
td,
td {
  border: 2px solid black;
}

.scrollable {
  overflow: auto;
  //height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><textarea></textarea></td>
      <td>
        <div class="scrollable">
          this is some really really really really really<br> really really really really really really really<br> really really really really really really really<br> really really really really really really really<br> really really really really really
          really really<br> really really really really really really really<br> really really really really really really really<br> really really really really really really really<br> long content
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this? It makes the inner text a specific height, and than that box scrolls:

```css
td, td {
    border: 2px solid black;
}

.scrollable {
  overflow: auto;
  height: 20px;
}
.inner{
  top: 0px;
  height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<table>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td><textarea></textarea></td>
          <td  class="scrollable">
            <div class="inner">
              this is some really really really really really<br>
              really really really really really really really<br>
              really really really really really really really<br>
              really really really really really really really<br>
              really really really really really really really<br>
              really really really really really really really<br>
              really really really really really really really<br>
              really really really really really really really<br>
              long content
            </div>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: No, this is exactly what I do not want. The scrollable text should take up all the available height. With the available height being determined by the height of the textarea.
Short text area, short displayed text, lots to scroll. Large text area, large displayed text, less to scroll.

Comment: What if the area is larger than the text? Do you want to adjust the line spacing? Text size? How do you want to fill up the space in the text section if the box is larger than the space that the current text will take up at its maximum?

Comment: the same way it behaves in my example above. Just show the complete text without hiding anything. No extra spacing needed, just as if I was to put raw text inside the td elements.

Comment: ?? So then whats wrong with the example you provided? Please make your question clearer

Comment: turns out this is a misunderstanding. I use firefox where the text overflows the table. In chrome it behaves almost as I expect, I would just prefer if the text was not stuck to the bottom but positioned in the center.
But a solution that is not viable on all browsers is sadly not enough for me.
The problem with my example is that it does not overflow at all.

Answer (score -2):

You can use something like

```
 <textarea rows="4" cols="50">
 Your content for example
 </textarea>
```